# Add time to ISO 8601 times in Perl

Tags: perl, iso

I have an ISO 8601 time stored in a variable and I have some number of hours stored in another variable like this:

```
my $current_time = shift; #looks like: 2015-07-01T15:38:08Z
my $hours = shift; # looks like: 12
```

My goal is to add the hours to the current time, but there doesn't seem to be any built in Perl function to do it. In Powershell, you can do something like this:

```
$currentTime = $currentTime .AddHours($hours)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Perl?

Comment: `$current_time = @_` will assign the number of elements in `@_`.

Comment: true, but I'm only ever passing in one thing, which is the current_time

Comment: So, it's equivalent to `$current_time = 1`. Use `shift` or `my ($current_time)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather easy with [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $current_time = '2015-07-01T15:38:08Z';
my $hours = 12;

my $format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ';
my $time = 'Time::Piece'->strptime($current_time, $format);
$time += $hours * ONE_HOUR;

print $time->strftime($format), "\n";
```

Comment: This added the hours beautifully, but it converted the format to  `Wed Jul  1 15:38:08 2015` Is there a way to preserve the ISO 8061 format?

Comment: @user3270760: See the `strftime` method.

Comment: Got it: `$new_time = $new_time -> strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ');'` in case there is future interest. Thanks!

Comment: `$time->datetime` will give you ISO 8601 format too.

Comment: @Matt Jacob, That uses a different ISO 8601 profile than the input (`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` instead of `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`). You'd need `$time->datetime . 'Z'`.

Comment: So add a `Z` to the end! Seems easier than specifying the entire format string. (Or just store the format string in a variable since it's the same for input and output.)

Answer (score 5):

That specific ISO 8601 profile is also known as RFC3339.

```
use DateTime::Format::RFC3339;

my $dt = DateTime::Format::RFC3339->parse_datetime('2015-07-01T15:38:08Z');
$dt->add( hours => 1 );
print "$dt\n";  # 2015-07-01T16:38:08Z
```

If you want to accept arbitrary ISO 8601 profiles, you can use DateTime::Format::ISO8601.

```
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime('2015-07-01T15:38:08Z');
$dt->set_time_zone('UTC');  # Convert to UTC ("Z") if it's not already.
$dt->add( hours => 1 );
print $dt->iso8601().'Z', "\n";  # 2015-07-01T16:38:08Z
```

I posted these alternatives because these modules are far less error-prone to use than Time::Piece.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Time-Moment/lib/Time/Moment.pod). In the interest of full disclosure, I am the author of Time::Moment.

```
say Time::Moment->from_string('2015-07-01T15:38:08Z')
                ->plus_hours(1);
```

Output:

```
2015-07-01T16:38:08Z
```